# Compare the Greater than elements in a vector in r

Tags: r, apply

I have this data frame which consists of two vectors and it runs into million of rows. I used loop but it takes a day to compare the value.
Can some one suggest any apply functions??
Names  Sales
A       1
A       2
A       3
B       1
B       5
B       6
.
.

what I want is unique list of names along with the maximum element in sales against that particular name. like A has 3 rows and highest sales is 3.

Output should be in data frame.
Names  Sales
A          3
B          6

Comment: You could use dplyr. `dat %>% group_by(Names) %>% summarise(Sales = max(Sales)) %>% data.frame()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `aggregate()`

```
aggregate(V2 ~ ., df1 , max)
#  V1 V2
#1  A  3
#2  B  6
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L)),
.Names = c("V1","V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Hello it worked but what if I have missing values it skips those like                                                         names Cat_A  Cat_B                                                                                                              A            1            NA                                                                                           B            NA         NA                                                                                          if i use the above aggregate function it skips B which has NA in both Cat_A & Cat_B but still want A.

Comment: The default option of handling `NA` in aggregate is `na.omit`, which means that any missing value is ignored. You can change this behavior by specifying the `na.action` parameter, like `aggregate(Cat_A ~ ., df1 , max, na.action = na.pass)` but this will probably create problems with the `max` function. I think I haven't understood what your desired output would be in the case of NA's. Maybe you want to ask a new question, since this was not part of your original post.